# Using powershell in pipeline how to get shelveset number using which pipeline run got triggered in azure devops

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines, tfvc

Using powershell in pipeline how to get shelveset number using which pipeline run got triggered in azure devops. Tfs repos.
I want to know how to get shelve set number.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Looked at the documentation?

Comment: See following : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cant-find-the-rest-of-my-shelvesets/149630

Comment: @DanielMann I tried to search documents but didn’t get anything , I want shelve set number in azure pipeline from which pipeline got triggered.

Comment: @jdweng I see that page is for to get all shelves set not the one from which pipeline triggered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services). There is a predefined variable containing that information, you don't need to do anything to retrieve it.

> Build.SourceTfvcShelveset

> Defined if your repository is Team Foundation Version Control.
> If you are running a gated build or a shelveset build, this is set to the name of the shelveset you are building.
> Note: This variable yields a value that is invalid for build use in a build number format.